# .addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is fairly simple. The .addEventListener isn't working for 'click' or 'change.' I had to put "onclick" inside my HTML but, as far as I know, there's no 'onChange' event in HTML. I'm trying to make a custom video player but the seek slider isn't working out. I was wondering how I could make .addEventListener work? (p.s., it hadn't worked before this question either)
HTML:

```
<div id="video_player_box">
            <video id="my_video" controls autoplay>
                <source src="/videos/video.mp4">
            </video>
            <div id="video_control_bar">
                <button id="playpausebutton" onclick="playPause()">Pause</button>
                <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
            </div>
        </div>
```

and JS:

```
var vid, playBtn, seekslider;

            function initPlayer() {
                vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
                playBtn = window.getElementById("playpausebutton");
                seekslider = window.getElementById("seekslider");

                seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
            }

            window.onload = initPlayer;

            function playPause() {

                if (vid.paused) {
                    vid.play();
                    playBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
                } else {
                    vid.pause();
                    playBtn.innerHTML = "Play";
                }
            }
            function vidSeek() {
                var seekTo = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
                vid.currentTime = seekTo;
            }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(id);` not `window.getElementById(id)` - your browser console will have an error like `Uncaught TypeError: window.getElementById is not a function`

Comment: Why do you think there's no `onchange`? All events have a corresponding `onXXX` attribute.

Comment: never used it nor heard of it, but I did try it and it didn't work

Comment: If you don't set `seekslider` correctly, it doesn't matter if you use `onchange` or `addEventListener`.

Comment: Close as a simple typo?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fuot0fov/1/ - Now the change handler is called... since there is no video found the seek operation is failing with error

Comment: @BrendonBaughn The question is did you try the above solution... maybes wont work.... either it works not didn't

Comment: @ArunPJohny That worked lol. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

fix your js code with this code:

```
var vid, playBtn, seekslider;

        function initPlayer() {
            vid = document.getElementById("my_video");
            playBtn = document.getElementById("playpausebutton");
            seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
            seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
        }

        window.onload = initPlayer;
        function playPause() {
            if (vid.paused) {
                vid.play();
                playBtn.innerHTML = "Pause";
            } else {
                vid.pause();
                playBtn.innerHTML = "Play";
            }
        }

        function vidSeek() {
            var seekTo = vid.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
            vid.currentTime = seekTo;
        }
```